# Is there a .emacs file available to make its keybindings behave like any modern IDE?

Tags: emacs, configuration, key-bindings

I learned programming with GUI editors such as Notepad++, Gedit, Netbeans and so on, so I'm used to some keybindings common in almost all of these programs (and some others like LO Writer, etc).

Is there any place where I can find a .emacs file that makes it work like that, so I can have all its power without spending half of my life in learning its keybindings or configuring it?

Comment: Whats the point of using emacs then?

Comment: I'm sure you can find something or write your own since these "GUI editors" often rely on the mouse rather than on the keyboard for most things. However, you're missing out on what makes Emacs powerful if you do this. Spend time to learn the keybindings and after a while, your productivity gains will more than compensate you for the time you spent.

Comment: @zsquare the point of emacs is not the keybindings, but the customizability/programmability

Comment: You can do this, but you will almost certainly run into problems with libraries expecting that X is the standard binding for a certain kind of functionality, when you like to use Y instead; so even if you find a pre-made configuration, *keeping* everything consistent with your preferences may be an ongoing task. That's one of the reasons that most people don't end up doing this. But if that's what you want to do, there's certainly nothing to stop you. This article will be a good resource for you: http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2011/02/08/mastering-key-bindings-emacs/

Comment: I want to learn more deeply Emacs only if I see it is worthy. I just think it's easier to start if the program adapts to me instead of the contrary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might try [ErgoMacs](http://ergoemacs.org/) which was built to modernize Emacs.  I haven't tried it since when I found it I already had too many of my own keybindings to switch, but if I were starting over, I'm pretty sure I would use it.

Comment: Definitely ErgoEmacs is the best way to start. CUA bindings, ergonomic bindings and many more stuff. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[cua-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/CuaMode) remaps emacs to use the key bindings that most other programs use.  It is built in to emacs and you can enable it in your `.emacs` with:

```
(cua-mode t)
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit on what you mean. There are ways to make Emacs use keyboard shortcuts that are standard in Windows, as e.g. pointed out by ataylor. However, when you say you want it to behave more like an *IDE*, it seems that you're not only interested in text editing keybindings (such as, moving the point, copy and paste, marking a region, etc.), but specifically for the functionality offered by IDEs: compiling, management of code projects, deployment, code refactoring, etc.

But Emacs is not an IDE. It's a text editor. Okay, it really is a lisp interpreter based around a visual model of text buffers.

As such it can do many tasks that IDEs do, but out of the box, IDEs do many of the tasks mentioned above better because they are made for these tasks. Since Emacs is just a lisp interpreter, a lot of people have written extensions to its core functionality, in form of so called "modes". So, yes, by installing the right modes on top of a vanilla Emacs you can make it a pretty powerful tool that can compete with IDEs.

But that doesn't go without *spending half of my life in learning its keybindings or configuring it*. Well, half your life is a bit of a stretch. Emacs has a [steep learning curve](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/988), that's true, but it's worth it -- because it is *not* an IDE. It's more than that.

If you're not willing to learn new stuff, than maybe you might want to take a moment and reconsider whether programming really is for you. Because the IT landscape changes very quickly all the time. Maybe in five years, Java is dead and no-one uses Eclipse any more. But you can be pretty sure of one thing: Emacs will still be around.

Okay, the last paragraph was total FUD, so ignore it. But seriously, learning new keybindings is not as hard as you think. And it doesn't take thaaat long either. You could re-configure and re-assign completely to your own liking in Emacs, but why not give the standard keybindings a chance?

Comment: Well the point here was that I was reading wonders about Emacs (and vi, but Emacs attracted me more), but for some time I discarded it because of becoming crazy just to select some text, copy it here and paste it there. I'm sure the default keybindings provide maximum efficiency, but *before* learning all that stuff, I want to take it easier for some time and see by myself if it is worth learning it. Thanks for your great answer anyway.

Comment: @Yajo Ah, don't worry, just jump into the cold water! Here's a website that helps you train your muscle memory: https://www.shortcutfoo.com/